# Upgrade/Change from CentOS to CentOS Atomic

Tags: centos, centos7

Is there a described path to change/update/upgrade from an base CentOS to CentOS Atomic?

```
[root@m1 ~]# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

Comment: I think it's an unlikely that there's a conversion path: Atomic is fundamentally different in how it manages the filesystem. I suspect the answer is "reinstall".

Comment: Sad! My server host provider only offers an base CentOS. So i have to go the long way to install my own OS on the server... @Larsks: Thx for sharing your opinion.

Comment: Who is your server provider? Exactly what sort of virtual machine have they given you? There is usually a way to work around the provider and install any distro you want, but we do need to know what you have available to work with.

Comment: My server provider is 1und1. At 1und1 there are options to install own operating systems. Unfortunately my first try to install CentOS Atomic with the [Generic Cloud Images] [1] myself failed yesterday. The system was only booting to the end in developer mode. At normal startup it was hanging...   [1]: https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/Atomic/Download/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no migration path from CentOS to CentOS Atomic or vice versa. Each of these installs a completely different layout of files, managed in a completely different way. You will need to do a fresh installation in order to get CentOS Atomic.